# Install mcrypt for php54 on centos 6.5

Tags: centos, php, mcrypt

I'm completely new to VPS and am trying to install php54 on a centos6.5 server.

I've updgraded the php version to 5.4 which appears to work. Currently using php5.4.31

However I now need to install mcrypt. I've tried:

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

I have set up remi and epel repositories and this goes so far to install but comes up with a dependency error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
No such command: snstall. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help
[root@XXXX~]# yum install php-mcrypt*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                            |  26 kB     00:00
 * base: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * extras: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: centos.hyve.com
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                          | 4.4 MB     00:01
epel                                                     | 4.4 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                          | 6.3 MB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                        |  19 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge/primary_db                                      | 2.7 MB     00:04
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                       | 4.7 MB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-  3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Installed: php-common-5.4.31-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(api) = 20090626
       Installed: php-common-5.4.31-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I cant seem to install mcrypt for version 5.4.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remi repository, from which you installed PHP, is disabled. Enable it and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt realise it had been disabled - I assumed once installed it would be enabled - still learning. mcrypt is now installed. Thanks

Comment: @Ray Remi ships the repo disabled by default, which is slightly annoying and leads to confusing issues like this.

Comment: The repository is not enabled by default because it overrides some base packages, and admin need to choose between remi, remi-php55, remi-php56, remi-php70 or remi-php71. See: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/